# How to make Gtk spinbutton symbolic in 12.04 in only a specific application?

Tags: application-development, python, themes, gtk3

I am currently developing an application for Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 12.10 systems. My application is completely monochromatic except for the spinbuttons as seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

This issue is only persistent in 12.04 since in 12.10 the spinbuttons by default are monochromatic. How do I convert this into something like below,

[image]

Please state how to ensure this is local to my application alone since I do not want to be messing around with system files, users wont like that.

How do this I solve this?